# assigning method to another method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of javascript objects that each have a setup method.  The code is identical for all of them so I created a function called setupMain.  Then for each instance of the object I'm trying to set it's setup value to setupMain.  something like below... but when I look at the setup value after an instance is created, it's coming back undefined instead of pointing to the setupMain function.  Any idea why?  Thanks.

```
var customObject = function(){
  this.title = "";
}
var setupMain = function(obj){
  obj.title = "initial setup value";
}

var co = new customObject();
co.setup = setupMain(co);
```

Comment: `co.setup` is undefined because you're calling the function `setupMain`, which has no return value.

Comment: Okay, so what do I return then to get it to assign the function and it's contents to co.setup?  Thanks.

Comment: Added my answer below, lemme know if it's not clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
var customObject = function(){
  this.title = "";
}
var setupMain = function(){ //"This" will point to instance, such as co
  this.title = "initial setup value";
}

var co = new customObject();
co.setup = setupMain; //Reference to function

co.setup(); //Call the setup function
window.alert(co.title);
```

Also, if you don't want to have to keep setting the `setup` function each time to create an instance, you can move it to the prototype:

```
customObject.prototype.setup = setupMain; //Now, every customObject has a setup function
var co = new customObject();
co.setup();
window.alert(co.title);
```

Finally, if you didn't want to have to call `setup();` each time, you can call `setup` within the constructor:

```
var customObject = function(){
  this.setup(); //Call shared setupMain function because it's part of the prototype
}
var setupMain = function(){
  this.title = "initial setup value";
}

customObject.prototype.setup = setupMain; //This can be shared across many prototypes

var co = new customObject();
window.alert(co.title);
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code evaluates setupMain(co) and assigns the result to c.setup... Therefore:

- setupMain sets co.title to "initial setup value"
- setupMain returns undefined
- co.setup is set to undefined

You should assign the function to your variable, such as:

```
var setupMain = function() {
    this.title = "initial setup value";
}
...
co.setup = setupMain; // Without the ()
```